# Software to generate fake user names and avatars

Tags: web-apps, user-interface, user-management

I'm looking for software to generate fake usernames and avatars for anonymous users. Essentially the same functionality that's present in Google Docs that shows a name like "Blue Panda" when an anonymous user is viewing a doc, along with an avatar of a blue panda.

The software should:

- Generate a fake username (e.g., "Purple Puppy")
- Generate an icon that matches visually with that fake username (e.g., an image of a purple puppy).

Ideally self-hosted. It's for use in a web app. Gratis would be nice but if there are non-free options I would still be interested

Comment: For random avatars, [Robohash](https://robohash.org) is my goto resource. But matching usernames would require some work.

Comment: Are you building this web app? Because if you are then I probably could make something if you can use a DLL or .net

Comment: I am building it, but it's NodeJS / Python

Comment: Not eactly what you're looking for but [RandomUser](https://randomuser.me/) allows you to generate profile pictures, names, emails, etc. randomly.

Comment: @AidenGrossman  Reall???!!!! A DLL Or .NET (windows specific) for an internet app????

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Scripting

If you don't mind using a <strike>programming</strike> script language... [Faker for Python](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) can generate fake usernames, names, addresses and much more.

Just install Python and then

```
pip install fake-factory
```

After that:

```
from faker import Factory
fake = Factory.create()
# OR from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
fake.name()
# 'Lucy Cechtelar'
fake.address()
# "426 Jordy Lodge
# Cartwrightshire, SC 88120-6700"
```

Source: [Faker Github page](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/README.rst)

## 2.Online

If you don't need the power of Python, you can also use https://fakena.me.

For avatars you can use [Gravatar home page](https://gravatar.com).